# How many ways to make a score of N?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, permutations

In a game, there are three possible shots making points 3,5, and 10 respectively.
A player has scored exactly N points. What are the scoring sequences possible? This was the original problem I was given.

For instance, for N = 15, the four possible scoring sequences are:

- 3,3,3,3,3
- 5,5,5
- 10,5
- 5,10

This is a programming question and I could come up with a solution to figure out the exact sequences(using dynamic programming). The trouble I am having is with estimating the time complexity of this approach. More precisely, I am trying to figure out the number of solutions possible for a given N. For example, for N=15, the number of scoring sequences is 4. How can we mathematically come up with a bound for the number of scoring sequences of N if the three possible scores are 3, 5, and 10?

Comment: Probably best to solve this is a recursive function : First score is $3$, $5$ or $10$ generate the possible combinations for the remaining score etc.

Comment: If the order matters, the function will not produce a sequence twice.

Comment: @5xum How? Note that he counts "5, 10" and "10, 5" as separate.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger Oh, right. Then forget what I said...

Comment: Also sprach Mathematica (working on what follows from Akiva Weinberger's answer): The smallest solution (in terms of absolute value) of $1-x^3-x^5-x^{10}=0$ is $\alpha\approx0.809698$. We have $1/\alpha\approx1.23503$. Therefore the number of sequences scoring up to $N$, call it $S(N)$, is asymptotically like
$$S(N)\approx K\cdot1.23503^N$$ for some constant $K$. I don't know the value of $K$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Could you elaborate and write it up an answer? I can understand till 0.809698, why do we consider 1 over it and how do you work out final result?

Comment: May be later today. I need to commute next, so I leave the stage for others for now. The method of solving a recurrence relation like this in terms of the zeros of the feedback polynomial is quite widely understood.

Comment: @Aravind Basically, assume that — for $N$ large enough — $f(N)$ (or $S(N)$ as he wrote it) is approximately equal to $K\alpha^N$ for some constants $K$ and $\alpha$. Using the recurrence relation, we get that $\alpha$ is a root of $x^{10}-x^7-x^5-1$. The root with the largest absolute value is $1.23503$. (This also happens to be the reciprocal of the polynomial in Jyrki's comment.)

Comment: It turns out that the exact solution is of the following form:$$f(N)=K_1\alpha_1^N+K_2\alpha_2^N+\dotsb+K_{10}\alpha_{10}^N$$where the $\alpha$s are the roots of that polynomial (real and complex). The root with the largest absolute value contributes the most to this sum, and that root is $1.23503$.

Answer (score 2):

You can define your function recursively:
$$f(n)=f(n-3)+f(n-5)+f(n-10),\\\text{for all }n>0$$
With initial conditions:
\begin{align}
f(n)&=0,&\text{for all }n<0\\
f(0)&=1
\end{align}
(There's only one sequence that gets us $0$ points: the empty sequence. Note that $n=0$ does not satisfy the recurrence relation.)

Proof for the recurrence relation: there are $f(n-3)$ sequences that begin with $3$, $f(n-5)$ sequences that begin with $5$, and $f(n-10)$ sequences that begin with $10$.

Comment: Yes, that's the recurrence that I used while coding it. But, how do we solve for the number of scoring sequences for a given N using this?

Comment: What do you mean? Like, you want to define $f$ without using recurrence relations?

Comment: No, I agree with this recurrence, but how do I work out the number of scoring sequences from this? I think @JyrkiLahtonen in his comment is trying to show that. Could one of you elaborate on how JyrkiLahtonen goes with that analysis?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just interested in the number of ways without giving importance to the order, you would essentially need the number of non-negative integer solutions to
$$3x+5y+10z = N$$
Equivalently, we would need the coefficient of $a^N$ in
$$\dfrac1{1-a^3}\cdot\dfrac1{1-a^5}\cdot\dfrac1{1-a^{10}} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} c(k)a^k$$

Comment: Note that he counts "10, 5" and "5, 10" as separate…

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger Oh. Good point.

Comment: He wants the coefficient of $a^N$ of $\dfrac1{1-a^3-a^5-a^{10}}$, I think.

Comment: I am not very strong with this kind of mathematics. How did you get the second equation from the first one? Is there somewhere I can read about this? Also, given the second equation, how would we work out the coefficient for the case of, say N=15?

Answer (score 0):

If the order of the terms didn't matter, you could use ordinary generating functions to answer this question.  However, since the ordering matters, you need exponential generating functions.  The coefficient of $\frac{t^m}{m!}x^n$ in
$$f(x,t) = \exp(t(x^3+x^5+x^{10}))$$
gives the number of sequences of $m$ shots whose total score is $n$.  Put another way, expand
$$f(x,t) = \sum_{n\ge0} p_n(t) x^n$$
where $p_n(t)$ is a polynomial in $t$. Then replace each $t^m$ in $p_n(t)$ by $m!$ to get the total number of sequences of shots, of all possible lengths, whose total score is $n$.

As an example, if you ask Wolfram Alpha for the Taylor series of $f(x,t)$, you get
$$1+t x^3+t x^5+(t^2 x^6)/2+t^2 x^8+(t^3 x^9)/6+1/2\, t (t+2) x^{10}+(t^3 x^{11})/2+(t^4 x^{12})/24+1/2\, t^2 (t+2) x^{13}+(t^4 x^{14})/6+1/120\, t^2 (t^3+20 t+120) x^{15}+ O(x^{16}).$$

To recover the count for $n=15$, we have
$$p_{15}(t)=1/120\, t^2(t^3+20t+120) = (t^5+20t^3+120t^2)/120.$$
Replacing $t^m$ with $m!$ gives $(120 + 20(6) + 120(2))/120 = 4$. (In fact, breaking this apart, this tells you there's one sequence with $5$ terms, one sequence with $3$ terms, and two sequences with $2$ terms.)

Comment: "Replacing $t^m$ with $m!$" is equivalent to "multiply by $e^{-t}dt$ and integrate from $0$ to $\infty$," using the integral for the Gamma function. Using your function $f(x,t)$ and doing this, we get:$$\frac1{1-x^3-x^5-x^{10}}$$as the final generating function, which I mentioned in the comments to Leg's (incorrect) answer and is equivalent to my answer.

Comment: (Well, by Leg's answer being "incorrect" I really mean that it's "the right answer to the wrong question." Actually, I think my answer answers the wrong question, too, in that OP wanted an explicit equation rather than a recurrence relation.)